# Config httponly and samesite on owasp anti-csrf on PHP

Tags: php, cookies, owasp, samesite, httponly

I am using OWASP anti CSRF ( https://owasp.org/www-project-csrfprotector/ ), but I need to configure the anti-csrf cookie with httponly and samesite. After reading all documentation I couldn't find how to set this parameters for the cookie.

https://github.com/mebjas/CSRF-Protector-PHP/wiki/Configurations

On "cookieconfig" it says that is an array with 3 properties:  path, domain, secure, which I am using. And it also says that sets the properties when using "setcookie" on PHP, so I thought I could use setcookie parameters "httponly" and "samesite", but it didn't work.

For now, I manually changed the source code for the anti-csrf setcookie() command (vendor/owasp/csrf-protector-php/libs/csrf/csrfprotector.php:417). But I don't like to change source code, I think there should be a better way, but the source code doesn't seems to consider it

Original code:

```
setcookie(
            self::$config['CSRFP_TOKEN'], 
            $token,
            time() + self::$cookieConfig->expire,
            self::$cookieConfig->path,
            self::$cookieConfig->domain,
            (bool) self::$cookieConfig->secure);
```

New code:

```
setcookie(
            self::$config['CSRFP_TOKEN'], 
            $token,
            array(
                'expires' => time() + self::$cookieConfig->expire,
                'path' => self::$cookieConfig->path,
                'domain' => self::$cookieConfig->domain,
                'secure' => (bool) self::$cookieConfig->secure,
                //'httponly' => true,
                'samesite' => 'Strict',
            )
        );
```

I had to comment httponly because AJAX is not working with it.